Two geometries in same layer
I've seen a base layer with two geometries: point (geomp) and surface (geoms). I'm trying to do this in PostGIS with :
    CREATE TABLE gestion (
    id_gestion INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    type text NOT NULL,
    fonctionl text NOT NULL,
    geomp public.geometry(point, 2154) NOT NULL,
    geoms public.geometry(polygon, 2154) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_gestion PRIMARY KEY (id_gestion)

Two questions :
how can I to fill geomp with centroids from an existing polygon layer ?
how can I fill both geometries in the same time when I create a feature ?

So are you asking how to use ST_Centroid() or ST_PointOnSurface()?

That's right, PointOnSurface is better for this.

What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [Edit] the Question to include your INSERT code attempt.

Maybe an insert with two geometries? Maybe an update deriving the points from the existing polygons? Maybe a trigger doing this automatically? Maybe having the layer loaded twice in a GIS (once per geometry column)? --> what have you tried?

I'm just looking for the best solution, asking if anyone else is doing it. Insert and update only work in the table. Difficult to do from GIS software. The trigger seems fine to me. If not, should I include a STORED column? I'll type in the best practice, if it exists.
